# Converting string to wchar_t (wide character) C++

Tags: c++

I want to know how I can convert `string str = "whatever"` to `wchar_t` so that the string can be stored as `wchar_t chResponse[] = ...(converted from string)..`

I am trying the following code:

```
string str = "whatever";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> utf8conv;
auto w_result = utf8conv.from_bytes(str); // convert utf8 to wchar_t
wchar_t chResponse[] = w_result;
```

Its giving me this error:

```
error C2075: 'chResponse' : array initialization needs curly braces
```

Comment: Look into `std::wstring_convert`.

Comment: can you please give me an example. I am trying the following code:
    `string str = "whatever";
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> utf8conv;
    auto w_result = utf8conv.from_bytes(str); // convert utf8 to    wchar_t wchar_t chResponse[] = w_result;`
Its giving me this error: `error C2075: 'chResponse' : array initialization needs curly braces`

Comment: Look to your right. This has been asked a million times.

Comment: @user1319424, You need to copy the result into your buffer if you want it non-const.

Comment: I am so confused. Can someone please just tell me how to convert this. I am not able to understand where m i going wrong. Can you please just write a snippet for the conversion??